# php экспорт в excel изображений

Tags: php, excel, php7, phpexcel

подскажите, как в ячейку закинуть несколько изображение? сейчас только 1-но вставляет, а нужно из папки все фото

```
$imagePath = dirname ( __FILE__ ) . '/image.jpg';
if (file_exists($imagePath)) {
$logo = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing();
$logo->setPath($imagePath);
$logo->setCoordinates("A2");   
$logo->setOffsetX(0);
$logo->setOffsetY(0);
$sheet->getRowDimension(2)->setRowHeight(190);
$logo->setWorksheet($sheet);
}
```

Comment: дак прочитайте содержимое папки и в цикле поместите, только не понятно зачем все в одну ячейку помещать

Comment: идет выгрузка товаров, и в последней колонке думал выгрузить фото, а как поместить в ячейку, если я этот код помещу в цикл не будет заменяться содержимое ячейки?

Comment: То есть у товара все таки одно фото? Если так, то выводите все в цикле, только вместо ячейки "А2" используйте "A".$i, где $i - инкрементная переменная.

Comment: нет у меня 2-5 фоток у товара, и я не знаю как их выгрузить в ячейку

Comment: в таком случае я понимаю, что каждое фото относится как модификация товара? возможно товары лучше дублировать в выгрузке по количеству фото, либо попробуйте в строчку записывать по ячейкам

Comment: В конечном файле в одной ячейке будет каша из фоток, не делайте так

Comment: а как мне написать, чтобы брал ячейки для фоток с L, потому что фоток может быть как 1 так и 7